# KKT condition just binding and inactive

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have read the textbook saying that if both KKT and Lagrangian multiplier $\lambda$ are $0$, then the constraint is just binding, whereas if KKT multiplier is equal to 0, and Lagrangian multiplier is non-zero value, it is inactive constraint.

As far as I know, KKT and Lagrangian function looks the same. How do we have different multiplier value from KKT and Lagrangian?

Comment: What textbook? I've never heard the term "KKT multiplier".

Comment: It is Mathematics for Economics and Finance By Michael Harrison, Professor of Pediatric. I think they use the term interchangeably...

Comment: When I get Lagrangian multiplier equal to 0, what can I say about the constraint? All I know is that if constraint does not bind, then multiplier is 0. But the other way may not holds..

Comment: But in your question the terms "KKT  multiplier" and "Lagrange multiplier" are not being used interchangeably.

Comment: Yes, but I just borrowed term from the book. I have limited access to the book, because I am looking at the online version, so I assume they use it interchangeably

Answer (score 2):

Take, for example, only inequality constraints
$$
\min f(x)\qquad\text{subject to}\qquad g(x)\le 0,\ x\in X.
$$
KKT conditions are conic gradient conditions on $\nabla f$ and $\nabla g_k$ for *active* constraints $g_k$. It can be formalized as

1. $\nabla L=0$,
2. Complementary slackness $\lambda_k g_k=0$ meaning that inactive constraints do not contribute any nonzero terms in 1,
3. Feasibility constraints $\lambda\ge 0$, $x\in X$, $g(x)\le 0$.

"Just binding" constraint means that it is not important for 1 and 2 (multiplied by zero $\lambda_k$), but only for 3 (feasibility). Often it is because the corresponding constraint is inactive at the point ($g_k<0$), however, it is possible geometrically that an active constraint has $\lambda_k=0$, just in 2 it happens to be $0\cdot 0=0$, but it is very special coincidence. Summarizing,

- $g_k<0$ (inactive) $\Rightarrow$ $\lambda_k=0$ (just bindning)
- $\lambda_k=0$ does not imply $g_k$ is inactive in general.

Comment: Is there any way to check that if $g_k$ is binding when $\lambda_k=0$?

Comment: @user1292919 I am not sure I understand the question. When $\lambda_k=0$ the constraint $g_k$ is *just-binding* by definition. If you want to check whether $g_k(x)\le 0$ or not you simply set the point $x$ into the constraint.